# Where can I find EUROCONTROL's fuel coefficients for the B737?

Tags: fuel, datasets

I am trying to compare the fuel impact of different types of approaches, to compute the fuel flow I am using a model developped by Eurocontrol (Base of aircraft data). I am struggling to find the fuel coefficients necessary for the computation. Do you know where this data can be found ?

I am particularly interested in the B737 (-600,-700 and -800) and the A320, I have found this http://catsr.ite.gmu.edu/SYST660/B737_BADA.pdf which is exactly what I am looking for but I find the value of the second thrust specific fuel consumption coefficient (.10000E+15 kts) quite weird because it is very different from what I had read before. For example it's .14300E+04 kts for the B767-300 https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/field_tabs/content/documents/sesar/bada-b763-opf.pdf and I trust this link since it comes from Eurocontrol's website.
Does anyone know whether this data is accurate ?

Comment: Why don't you write an email to Eurocontrol [the BADA team] and explain them what you are doing. Apply for a license to BADA 3.latest, sign the NDA and get the data you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have just sent them an e-mail, since it's written on their website that licenses are only available for companies I am not sure I will get an answer though